# How to handle Alerts in chrome 64 using selenium Java?Getting chrome pop up as " Do you want to leave this site?"

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Handle alert

> Do you want to leave this site?

I am using chrome 64 for selenium Java.

Getting Below Error:

```
rg.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3253.3)
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Pxp.png)

Comment: If my answer does not help you out, please add what you have tried so others may better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle the Alert by doing something like this :

```
//Dismiss the alert
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

//Accept the alert
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Have a look at this [article](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) for more information about alert handling in selenium.

Comment: Hi,already done with this code and getting error "alert is not present "

Comment: Check out the suggested duplicate. If that does not Help, please be more specific in your questioning and show us Some code. This may be a different question but we simply cant tell without knowing more

Comment: Scenario: When i am going out my Website, Getting Pop up as "Do you want to leave this site,changes you made may not be saved".. i tried with robot class also but it works sometime only..

Answer (score 0):

You can use alert interface for that

```
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  alert.accept();   //for accept
  alert.dismiss();//for dismiss
```